# How to move a header to the right side while maintaining width?

Tags: css

I am having a problem moving my h2 header to the right side of the screen while maintaining a given width. I have tried display: flex and float: right but I can't seem to figure out how to effectively align the h2 div to the right side of the screen. My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/b62tg9un/19/

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Example Title</h1>
    <h2>This is a test sentence to work on my html and css code.</h2>
</div
```

```
h2 {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
.highlight {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: right;
        justify-items: right;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: could you please attach the screenshot of what you see on your browser ?

Comment: justify-items is for CSS GRID not CSS Flex, have you tried justify-content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the items in the flex container to align to the right side of the container, you should use `align-items: flex-end`

```css
h2 {
  width: 60%;
}

.container {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

this will still have the h1 and h2 layed out in a column, but the h2 only takes 60% of the width and is aligned to the right.

Comment: Thanks it was align-items and flex-end.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change to flex-direction to row , because you want both of these items to be in a row

If you cant get a good mental model of flexbox try this link. it is well described there.
[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}

.highlight {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content : space-between;
    }
```

[image: Here is my result]

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a bracket at the end. The last Div is not closed. Thats all.

You should use jsutify-content instead of justify-items tho for flex, and end instead of right

Comment: the accepted answer is good tho, align-items: flex-end should solve msot of it, i would also add a "text-align: end " to the h2 cause it still will look like whitespace on the right when your Text is not filling the fixed h2 width